# java jboss failed to process phase PARSE of deployment

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, war, ear

I run my war/ear file on Jboss 7 and get the following error:

```
"Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\PROJECTNAME.war\".
PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.services.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"PROJECTNAME.war\".
PARSE:  Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"PROJECTNAME.war\""}
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: It looks like your project war failed to deploy due to something wrong with a file that is misconfigured, normally it would be less cryptic.  Is there more to the stack trace?

Comment: Check your beans.xml, faces-config.xml, web.xml and your taglibs for erroneous tags.

Comment: There are number of configuration issues which can cause war deployment to fail. You need to check the web.xml. Also, there should be more errors in the log to indicate if something failed to start up or wired up etc. You need to check all the logs.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same message trying to run an ee8 WAR on WildFly 16 in standalone mode.  Assuming you are also running in standalone mode, ensure you set `--server-config=standalone-full.xml` after the standalone executable.